# What are these tag names <% and <%=?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp-classic

I tried searching SO, but I guess it doesn't like the syntax <%= in the query text so if this is a duplicate, I'll delete it.

My question is, what are the actual names of the following tags? What would i call them if describing them to someone else

```
<%
<%=
```

and if you know them

```
<%#
<%@
```

Comment: Voted to close as the link provided does answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% scriptlets
<%= expression
<%# expression
<%@ directives
```

**EDITED**
Imagine like this
1. Whatever you write within `<% %>` are placed in some 'process' function
2. Whatever you write inside <%@ %> are placed at class level
3. You can just write expressions inside `<%= %>` imagine something is written to print `Response.Write` (we also do not write ';' at the end eg. `<%= x+5 %>`)  and `<%# %>` is same as `<%= %>` but the difference is the way they function internally
NOTE: This is just for your understanding and not taken from any source.

Comment: While I have no reason to think you are incorrect, can you provide the source for the names?

Comment: hope this helps `http://forums.asp.net/p/1139381/1828702.aspx`

Answer (score 0):

<% is a "classic-asp" tag which is used to  write server-side code. You can name it scriptlets.You can use it in .net platform in c# also.
<%=  is not really a tag. It is used to write something.
%@ directives is used for directives